# EF Core: Why does Context return null when Subentity is null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I got an Error, which I found after several hours, but I would like to know why this happens.

When I have:

```
var ticket = context.Tickets.AsNoTracking().Include(x=>x.Creator).SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==ticketId);
```

Creator is of class "User".
I have added to "User" a "`bool Activated {get;set;}`" and this to a Global Query Filter "`.HasProperty(x=>x.Activated);`"
The problem is that the above Query will return null if "Activated" of the User is set to false (but only in the global Query filter).

Why does this happen? Shouldn´t just the "Creator" be null in that case?

Comment: Microsoft explains it pretty well here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#accessing-entity-with-query-filter-using-required-navigation

Comment: huh, why would there be an Inner JOIN instead of an Left Join used?

Comment: If your navigation property is not optional then JOIN will be inner.